# Using two columns as key in spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have 4 columns and many rows in my csv file.

```
Date(MM/DD/YY)  Arr_Dep     Dom_Int             Num_Fl
01/01/15 0:00   Arrival     Domestic            357
03/01/15 0:00   Arrival     International       269
06/01/15 0:00   Departure   Domestic            82
08/01/15 0:00   Departure   International        5
05/01/16 0:00   Arrival     Domestic            44
06/01/16 0:00   Arrival     Domestic            57
07/01/16 0:00   Departure   International       51
08/01/16 0:00   Departure   International       40
08/01/17 0:00   Arrival     Domestic            1996
10/01/17 0:00   Departure   International       21
```

I have to find the average number of flights per month in a particular year depending on whether the flight was arrival or departure. So output I'm expecting for the above input is:

```
2015, arrival, 313
2015, departure, 44
2016, arrival, 51
2016, departure, 46
2017, arrival, 1996
2017, departure, 21
```

I'm facing issue as to how should I include two columns in my key i.e. Arr_Dep and Date column in my map function to finally reduce it to get the average.
I have written following script so far. Not sure how to proceed

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from operator import add
import sys

sc = SparkContext(appName="example")
input_file = sys.argv[1]
lines = sc.textFile(input_file)
first = lines.map(lambda x : ((x.split(",")[0].split(" ")[0][5:]).encode('ascii','ignore'), int(x.split(",")[-1]), x.split(",")[1]))
second = first.filter(lambda x : "Arrival" in x[1] or "Departure" in x[1])
third = second.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1]))
result = third.reduceByKey("Not sure how to calculate average")
output = result.collect()
for v in sorted(output, key = lambda x:x[0]):
    print '%s, %s' % (v[0], v[1])
```

I'm not sure about the above script. I'm new to spark and python. Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use `SQL` API:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.options(inferSchema=True, header=True).csv(input_file)
df\
  .groupBy(year(to_date("Date(MM/DD/YY)", "MM/dd/yyH:mm")).alias("year"), "Arr_Dep")\
  .avg("Num_Fl")
```

Comment: But how do I calculate average using this? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I think he is calculating average using th avg function take a look !